# Unable to connect to MySQL server using -h option

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql server 5.5.8 in my windows 8.1 machine and configured SSL. I am able to login to mysql shell using `mysql -u <username> -p --ssl-ca=ca.pem` command. But when I use `mysql --ssl-ca=ca.pem -u <username> -p -h <ipaddress of my windows pc instead of localhost>` I am getting `Error 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to Mysql Server on <ip address> (10061)`.

I added `bind-address=0.0.0.0` to my.ini file before starting the mysql server.

my.ini is as follows.

```
    # Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:\mysql\data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port        = 3310
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.8
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.8/data

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
#skip-networking

# Disable Federated by default
skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
log-bin=mysql-bin

# binary logging format - mixed recommended
binlog_format=mixed

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#innodb_data_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = C:\mysql\data/
#innodb_log_arch_dir = C:\mysql\data/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port = 3310
ssl_ca=c:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.8\\certfiles\\ca.pem
ssl_cert=c:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.8\\certfiles\\server-cert.pem
ssl_key=c:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.8\\certfiles\\server-key.pem
```

Using `mysql -u root -p` command I entered in to mysql shell and executed below commands.

```
CREATE USER 'satya' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'satya'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd' REQUIRE SSL;
```

I have two entries in mysql.user table as follows.

```
satya    localhost
satya    %
```

Later I started wampmysqld from services.msc.

From windows PC prompt I executed below command.

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.2 -u satya -p -P 3310 --ssl-ca=ca.pem
```

I could successfully entered in to mysql shell.

Later when I tried above command from Ubuntu VM running in virtual box I am getting below error.

ERROR (2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.2' (111)

Now I am getting below error after trying below command from Ubuntu VM.

```
mysql -u satya -p -P 3310 -h 192.168.1.2 -ssl-ca=ca.pem -v
```

ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL Connection Error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed.

My mysql server version is 5.5.8 whereas when I tried mysql --version I got below information.

mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.34, for linux (x86_64) using Editline wrapper

Comment: Trivial question: Does a `ping` from your Ubuntu VM to your windows server work?

Comment: Yes, I tried ping as well as telnet 192.168.1.2 3310 command from Ubuntu VM. Both are working. 192.168.1.2 is where Mysql server is running and my Ubuntu Ip is 192.168.1.4

Comment: You have a `[wampmysqld]` section and a `[mysqld]` section in your MySQL server configuration file, but it looks like you are running the `wampmysqld` executable. Can you elaborate on this? Specially as only one of them has SSL related configurations. Also, does it work when you don't use SSL? Currently you are getting SSL related error messages, which are mentioned in other questions like https://serverfault.com/questions/839650/mysql-ssl-ssl-ctx-set-default-verify-paths-failed

Comment: I added ssl related options under wampmysqld section in my.ini file on windows machine and restarted wampmysqld.  With and without --ssl-ca it is working fine on Windows machine. On Ubuntu I am getting SSL_CTX_set... error.  In Ubuntu machine /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf file contains only one line [mysql].

Comment: Does the connection from the Ubuntu VM works when you don't use SSL? Please [edit] your question to include your findings when you try a connection without SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Check your users table to see if you have the Host(your ip address) added to the user with the priviledges.

By default the localhost will be in the host column in the mysql.user table.

If not, To grant access from another host, change the hostname part with the remote machine IP. For example, to grant access from a machine with IP 10.8.0.5 you would run:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'xx.xx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

To create a user that can connect from any host, use the '%' wildcard as a host part:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';
```

Then grant privileges accordingly:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'%';
```

Reload all privileges

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Result of select user, host from mysql.user is 'username' in first column and % in second column after login to mysql shell.

Comment: However the problem remains same.

Comment: When I tried mysql -u satya -p -h <ipaddress not localhost> --ssl-ca=ca.pem -P 3310 command from windows PC itself in whcih I am running mysqld service, it is working. However, When I tried the same command from ubuntu machine I am getting ERROR 2026: SSL Connection error : error : 00000001:lib(0): func(0):reason(1)    I stopped firewall in my windows PC and flushed iptables in Ubuntu.

Answer (score -4):

if you are using apache server like wamp or xampp then you must have confingure the port address. check the port is running 80

Comment: This is an issue related to Mysql connection, not apache/web server and port 80